# css not working after writing .htaccess

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was trying to get rid of my file extensions using .htaccess, it worked, but right now my CSS and images has stopped working. I have tried different things, but it's still not working. Please! I need help with this. Thanks in advance. All my php files are in the same directory which is the root folder and my css and image folder is in a different folder in my root folder. here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*/.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(css|img) - [L]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have made a rule that replaces all css files with `-`.

Comment: I don't and had no intention of replacing my CSS with anything, All I wanted to do was remove the PHP extension. After I did that and it worked, the CSS stopped working. I'm also not very good with .htaccess. Thanks

Comment: Could you share the old version of your .htaccess, and give some example urls for your php files and css files?

Comment: I used this to remove the extensions .......RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*/.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]......<a href="about.php"> , <link href="css/style.css"/>. Thanks in advance

Comment: That is the same code you already posted. What was the change you made?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding you. I don't have any previous .htaccess. I only have this one. which is what removed the PHP extension and triggered the CSS problem.

Comment: That last line, what does it do? What do you *expect* it to do? Why is it there anyway?

Comment: I wanted it to remove the file extension. I had used this code a while ago on another project and it worked. Please you can help correct any errors as I have been struggling with this all day

Answer (score 1):

To add `.php` you just need this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

If you have a trailing slash in your pretty URL like `http://example.org/file/` then css/js relative paths will be resolved to `/file/css/` instead of `/css/` hence causing 404 for css/js files.

**To fix that** you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.